# Dual booting starting from Linux with LVM

Tags: partition, dual-boot, lvm, uefi, gparted

I currently run Arch Linux, and am quite familiar with Linux, however I'm not that familiar with partitioning and stuff.

When I set up my system, I decided to use LVM, though I'm not that familiar with it.

I want to shrink my LVM partition to make room for a Windows partition, for doing a bit of Windows gaming (since some anticheats say no on Linux)

I use UEFI

My current partitioning is:

EFI Partition

LVM2 PV

How could I shrink that LVM partition without any data loss? Don't wanna have to reinstall all of my programs.

Comment: I don't know if your plan will work. In my experience, Windows will take over the entire disk. To answer your question, the partition on which a PV resides can be shrunk if there is room at the end of the PV. If not, you will have to shrink or delete an LV. To shrink an LV, you will first have to shrink the filesystem that's on it (if thereis one). Too much hassle in my opinion, and too easy to destroy data. Since you need to take a backup anyway, I suggest installing Windows, then adding Arch and restoring the backup.

Comment: Before you can shrink the lvm, you need to shrink the filesystem in the lvm. I am not sure, but I guess "gparted" might help you do the job.

Comment: Can you add another disk to your system for Windows? If you can it’s easy. Remove you existing disk, install Windows on the new disk, replace the existing disk and update grub. It’s a bit more complicated than that but that’s the gist.